# Android app remain logged into website, cookies? Session?

Tags: android, authentication, session, cookies

I'm looking to make an android app that is basically a custom view of a text based gaming website. I know how to do HttpPosting and such, so sending login information is relatively simple. But my question is, how would I go about then navigating the site? I've never really worked with sessions and cookies on the client side. Is a cookie the right way to implement this? How do I pass the info back to the server when accessing subsequent pages?

I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

Generally, in Java HttpURLConnection you can set / get a cookie this way (here is the whole connection process). The code below is in my ConnectingThread's run(), from which all the connecting activity classes inherit. All share common static sCookie string which is sent with all the requests. Therefore you can maintain a common state like being logged on / off:

```
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();             

        //set cookie. sCookie is my static cookie string
        if(sCookie!=null && sCookie.length()>0){
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sCookie);                  
        }

        // Send data
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream(); 
        os.write(mData.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close(); 

        // Get the response!
        int httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();         
        if (httpResponseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
           throw new Exception("HTTP response code: "+httpResponseCode); 
        }

        // Get the data and pass them to the XML parser
        InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();                
        Xml.parse(inputStream, Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, mSaxHandler);                
        inputStream.close();

        //Get the cookie
        String cookie = conn.getHeaderField("set-cookie");
        if(cookie!=null && cookie.length()>0){
            sCookie = cookie;              
        }

        /*   many cookies handling:                  
        String responseHeaderName = null;
        for (int i=1; (responseHeaderName = conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i))!=null; i++) {
            if (responseHeaderName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {                  
            String cookie = conn.getHeaderField(i);   
            }
        }*/                

        conn.disconnect();
```