# Android DefaultHttpClient Session Check

Tags: android, session

I'm very new to Android programming and I have following doubt.

I use `DefaultHttpClient` for making Http calls to my server. It works fine.

Are there any way to check whether the session is still live on my `DefaultHttpClient` object?

Is that possible to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can answer your question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115357/android-app-remain-logged-into-website-cookies-session?rq=1